# Dornbusch Sticky Price (Overshooting) model

Tags: exchange-rates

[image]

Stupid question: What do the phi and lambda from the equations above represent?

Answer (score 1):

The equations you have are equilibrium conditions, while derivation (of course) starts with the demand equation and sets demand equal to supply. Then:

- $\varphi$ ($0<\varphi<1$) is the income elasticity of money demand - the responsiveness of demand with respect to income
- $-\lambda$ ($-\lambda <0$) is the interest rate semi-elasticity of money demand - the responsiveness of demand to the change in interest rates.

Semi-elasticity means that we care how much Y changes in percentages when we increase $X$ by one (increase by one, not by one percentage point).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, $\phi$ and $\lambda$ are simply positive parameters in the Dornbusch model used to represent the linear (in logarithms) equilibrium condition in the money market.

$$
m - p = \phi y - \lambda i
$$

is also known as the LM curve, in logarithms.